# user comments display on wordpress page

Tags: wordpress, comments, spam

looking to achieve something similar to this page where user can enter a thought into a form field and on submission this then posts straight onto the page.

http://hcma.ca/

Would using wordpress comments be best for this? Or some way of sending the form submission to populate a repeater advanced custom field on the page. Can anyone advise how best to achieve this?

Also wondering about spam. The site above has no captcha or similar (as far as I can tell). What's the deal with this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use a paid plugin, you can create a new Custom Post Type and then display the results on the page you want. You should follow this [tutorial here](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-create-custom-post-types-in-wordpress/)

In short:

Create a new post type:

```
// Our custom post type function
function create_posttype() {

    register_post_type( 'movies',
    // CPT Options
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Movies' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Movie' )
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'has_archive' => true,
            'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'movies'),
        )
    );
}
// Hooking up our function to theme setup
add_action( 'init', 'create_posttype' );
```

Display the results in a page:

```
<?php 
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'movies', 'posts_per_page' => 10 );
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); 
?>
<?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
<?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
<h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
<div class="entry-content">
<?php the_content(); ?> 
</div>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<?php else:  ?>
<p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

You can use then this free plugin to add [Google reCaptcha](https://wordpress.org/plugins/google-captcha/) to avoid spam

Comment: thanks Tasos, I get that but how would I have front end form that website visitors can fill in and this populates the CPT?

Comment: Check this answer where you can create a form submission for custom post types http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/11288/40793 If you are satisfied with the answer, you should mark it as accepted (The green tick) and vote it up if you want